# Do air particles always rush to fill a container?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas

I'm sitting here in the metro station, drinking a bottle of water, and watching how the flow of water out of my mouth changes as air rushes into the bottle. My questions is: in space, obviously the effect would be different. How is this effect different as compared to with earth, and can the change in behaviour be solely attributed to the effects of gravity?

Comment: Can you be more precise what your question is? I currently don't understand what behaviour you're talking about.

Comment: Gas particles of an ideal gas rush to fill their container. Does that behaviour still hold in space, or in areas of different relative gravitational pull? That's my question.

Comment: Yes, if you opened a bottle of water in empty space it would be very different.   The water would explode out of the bottle in a violent boil and quickly dissipate into gas.   If you opened a bottle of water in the space station, that wouldn't happen but the lack of gravity could cause circular drops of water to float out.   The effects are both gravity and air pressure.  Air pressure is the bigger one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. Does the ideal gas law describe this behaviour in space, as well?

Comment: Matt, as a broad model it sometimes helps to think of a gas as a lot of very small, very fast-moving billiard balls that bounce off of each other and any walls they hit. Put them next to a true empty space -- a vacuum -- and they quickly sail off into the wild dark yonder. BTW, I think the heart of your question is: If humans were OK in vacuums, and if they drank liquids that don't explode in vacuums, and you have gravity in both cases: Would taking a swig of your favorite bottled beverage be different? The answer is yes: Your drink would flow out unimpeded, with no need to let air flow in.

Answer (score 1):

Air molecules rush in all directions. There are a lot of molecules at the surface of the Earth. They continually bounce around, bumping into other air molecules or the walls of a container after traveling a microscopic distance.

An open bottle has air in it. At the mouth, molecules fly in and out equally. Overall, they don't move much.

If there was no air outside, the molecules at the mouth would have nothing to bump against. They would fly out.

Molecules bump hard. This is the cause of air pressure. If the area of the mouth was 1 square inch, there was no air outside, and you put your hand over the mouth to hold back the air, it would push on your hand with a force of 14.7 lb.

This is of course far more than the weight of the air inside a small bottle. At the surface of the Earth, a cubic yard of air weighs about 2 pounds.

However, gravity is ultimately the cause of air pressure at the surface of the earth. Without gravity, all the air would fly off into space. The 14.7 lb needed to keep air in an open bottle comes from the weight of a 1 square inch column of air above it.